# How to render [slug].js page after fetching data Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a logic for my `blog/:post` page in Next.js but I cannot seem to figure out how.

The idea is to:

1. Fetch the url (using `useRouter`)
2. Call API (it is a headless CMS) to get the info of the post
3. Render the post

What I have right now is:

```
[other imports ...]
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const apikey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BUTTER_CMS_API_KEY;
const butter = require('buttercms')(apikey);

function BlogPost(props) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug }  = router.query
  const [blogPost, setBlogPost] = useState({})

  // Function to the blog post
  function fetchBlogPost() {
    butter.post.retrieve(slug)
    .then(response => {
      const blogPostData = response.data.data
      setBlogPost(blogPostData)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // We need to add this if condition because the router wont grab the query in the first render
    if(!router.isReady) return;
    fetchBlogPost()
  }, [router.isReady])

  return (
    <>
      # Render post with the data fetched
    </>
  )
}

export default BlogPost;
```

But this is not rendering everything (the image is not being rendered for example). I believe it is because of the `pre-render` functionality that Next.js has. Also I have been reading about the `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` but I am unsure on how to use them properly.

Any guidance will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using next.js then you are on track with getStaticProps being your friend here!

Essentially getStaticProps allows you to take advantage of [ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) to fetch data on the server and create a static file of your page with all of the content returned from the fetch.

To do this you'll need to make an adjustment to your current architecture which will mean that instead of the slug coming in from a query param it will be a path parameter like this: `/blogs/:slug`

Also this file will need to be called `[slug].js` and live in (most likely) a `blogs` directory in your pages folder.

Then the file will look something like this:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const apikey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BUTTER_CMS_API_KEY;
const butter = require('buttercms')(apikey);

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    try {
        // You can query for all blog posts here to build out the cached files during application build

        return {
            paths:[], // this would be all of the paths returned from your query above
            fallback: true, // allows the component to render with a fallback (loading) state while the app creates a static file if there isn't one available.
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            paths: [],
            fallback: false,
        }
    }
}


export const getStaticProps = async ctx => {
    try {
        const { slug } = ctx.params || {}
        const response = await butter.post.retrieve(slug)

        if(!response.data?.data) throw new Error('No post data found') // This will cause a 404 for this slug

        return {
            notFound: false,
            props: {
                postData: response.data.data,
                slug,
            },
            revalidate: 5, // determines how long till the cached static file is invalidated.
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
            revalidate: 5,
        }
    }
}



function BlogPost(props) {
  const {isFallback} = useRouter() // We can render a loading state while the server creates a new page (or returns a 404).

  const {postData} = props
  // NOTE: postData might be undefined if isFallback is true

  return (
    <>
      # Render post with the data fetched
    </>
  )
}

export default BlogPost;
```

In any case, though if you decide to continue with rendering on the client instead then you might want to consider moving your fetch logic inside of the useEffect.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if your butter cms key is meant to be a secret, but going with [ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) also has the added benefit of allowing it to stay private if you want it to.

Comment: Thanks a lot @madze! So I guess that for updating the state I need to do it in the `BlogPost` function with the `props.postData`?

Comment: Also @madze, in `getStaticPaths` you wrote I can fetch all the blog posts. Does that mean that I do the fetching of all blog posts there and then in the `getStaticProps` I fetch the one coming from the url? Is that how it works? Thanks!

Comment: @josegp - Yes, sort of - in getStaticPaths you would make some kind of fetch to get all the blog post slugs so that these pages can be built as static files when the app builds. Then in getStaticProps you fetch the actual data for each individual post to render the static file with.

Comment: As far as updating state goes - there are a number of ways to manage state with next.js but, essentially props.postData is the initial state used to render the page. Any additional state can either be added via getStaticProps or else fetched client side (similar to how you were doing in your original question). However, you wouldn't update data passed in as a prop directly (if I'm understanding your question)